# Creating class objects

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Heap vs Stack allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713637/heap-vs-stack-allocation)

If I have the following class definition

```
class Student
{
string UniversityId;
string firstname;
string lastname;
};
```

What are the advantages and disadvantges of creating the Student Object on the stack or on the heap.

Comment: There is no such thing as "stack" or a "heap" in the language C++. What are you talking/worrying about? Perhaps you mean automatic vs. dynamic storage?

Comment: I don't think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713637/heap-vs-stack-allocation is explaining when should the object be allocated on the stack or on the heap?

Comment: There is a concept of heap memory or stack memory even in c++..

Comment: I think [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161991/when-should-i-allocate-on-the-heap-c) will help answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use automatic variables ('the stack') until explicit need for using free store ('the heap') arises.