# To heap or stack array. A user-defined type conundrum

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

### UPDATE

- Rewrote the question to better fit what I'm trying to ask.

When designing a mostly short-lived container that isn't big enough to warrant a heap allocation but isn't small enough that move semantics will not make any difference. How should one decide on which way to design the container so that it is performant (size/space is secondary to).

As far as I can see, there are two methods:

Method (A) implement internal data as a pointer and use heap allocation. `T* data = new T[]`

Method (B) implement stack array data structure. `T data[]`

I am new to C++ and have been reading up on many articles on SO regarding stack vs heap. This is what I currently gathered...

### Method (A)

advantages:

- No full struct/class memory allocation until required (can use nullptr on an empty constructor until initialised / assigned), though pointer still require 32 bit / 64 bit.
- Possible to make move constructible and move assignable.

disadvantage:

- must allocate per object (unless heap memory pooling is used)

### Method (B)

advantages:

- Stack memory is faster than heap (because acquiring stack memory only involves moving stack point vs heap allocation of finding continous block in a contented environment.)
- More likely to be in processor cache because memory locations are for "hot" data.

disadvantages:

- Not possible to move
- Must allocate memory immediately where it's declared.

If for example, given a user designed type that will be used to do a lot of calculations, which means a lot of temporaries. What would be the most performant way?

The heap array's ability to move, and when combined with nullptr the ability to do zero-copy seems to me like it would eliminate any advantage a stack would give, since moving involves only 1 pointer substition vs a medium sized array copy.

Are there factors I've missed or misunderstood? What would one generally need to know in order to decide which method to take?

Can the stack copy arrays of data faster than a heap move/pointer reassignment?

Comment: Method A - takes more memory, can be moved, requires VERY SLOW heap allocations.  Method B - takes _less memory_, can be copied _faster than A can be moved_.  In what way is B worse?  Use the heap for things of large dynamic size, and runtime polymorphism.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is with my question, why is a genuine question downvoted twice? You guys downvotes people who ask non-obvious questions nowadays? I do not have a full understanding of stack vs heap. This answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599308/. leads me to think stack and heap in hardware seems to be the same, as in, it uses a piece of physical memory, except one is pre-allocated and reserved. As such I fail to understand why stack copying of array would be faster than a pointer move/swap of a heap allocated array.

Comment: Unless what all those articles and answers on SO failed to mention is that the stack memory is guaranteed to reside on CPU cache? Even then in a multi-threaded environment, wouldn't that advantage be eliminated if there is a need for multi-thread store/load?

Comment: I'd downvoted since you are attempting to do vaguely advanced things with pointers that you don't actually know how to use.  On review, this was a stupid reason, and the question is actually surprisingly well written, so I changed that to a +1.

Comment: "except one is pre-allocated and reserved."  That makes copying really fast.  Also, the copy is only three bytes, and is only one way.  Moving a pointer would require moving four bytes, _and then zeroing the old data_.  Twice as many operations means it's only half the speed.  Stack memory is _usually_ thread specific, so they're is no store/load.  Anything the pointer version can do, the stack version can do better.

Comment: As a tip, `std::string` is written in insanely complex ways so that it can store data in a stack array data structure internally and avoid heap allocations.  Listen to the pros.  Do B.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't dynamically allocate if you're not sure whether you need it. Speed and space implications aside, it's simply more code to write and get right. Moreover, should *some* client code need indirection (e.g. to move efficiently, or to save space by omitting data), they can always add this from the outside: `std::unique_ptr<ModeratelyLargeType>` works fine.

Regarding the specific int24 type:

You should make it a struct containing three `uint8_t`s or some similar way of getting 24 bits directly into the object. I assume that's what you mean by "stack array". The "advantages" of method A and the corresponding "disadvantages" of method B you list are nonsense:

> [A +] No memory allocation until required (can use nullptr on an empty constructor until initialised / assigned)
>
> [B -] Must allocate memory immediately where it's declared.

Method A always needs to allocate a pointer, and the pointer is larger than the actual data (32 or 64 bits vs. 24 bits). Not only does method A use more than twice as much memory when actually used, it uses more memory even when not used. All of this without considering the space overhead of heap allocator metadata.

For completeness I should add, depending on how exactly you implement this, alignment may force the compiler to insert padding, making the structure larger than 24 bits but still no larger than a null pointer (so the above still stands). Likewise, it obviously won't use three quarters of a 32 bit register.

> [A +] Possible to make move constructible and move assignable.
>
> [B -] Not possible to move?

Well, you can move the pointer, but that's not more effective than copying three bytes. Again, the pointer is larger than the data it points at.

Comment: Right thank you, I had forgotten about the pointer size. However, my 2nd half of the question, if it wasn't about 3 bytes, but something that's larger than a pointer's worth of data. What then?

Comment: @rnc Depends heavily on how much larger, but unless it's really big (kilobytes or more), I'd default to not forcing a separate allocation. If null pointers and efficient moves are important, client code can still put the struct behind a pointer themselves. All assuming the size is known and a compile time constant.

Comment: "client code can still put the struct behind a pointer themselves", so you're saying the advantages of a heap allocation can be gained by using a wrapper if required on a basic struct that uses the stack. Am I reading you right?

Comment: @rnc No `struct` "uses the stack" (or the heap, or any other memory area). A struct *is*. If some code writes `new Foo`, memory is taken from the heap and given to the `Foo` object. If some code writes `Foo foo;`, memory is taken from the stack and given to the `Foo` object. And whatever the `struct Foo` contains, be it a pointer to some heap allocation or an array or any other data, is put into that memory. So yes, all code can put the objects (and hence all their data) onto the heap if it wishes.

Comment: right, I know all member variables are put on stack if one writes `Foo foo` instead of `new Foo`, but any explicit heap allocation is created on the heap, right? Your comment "And whatever the struct Foo contains, be it a pointer to some heap allocation or an array or any other data, is put into that memory" made me confused for a second. In anycase, "So yes, all code can put the objects (and hence all their data) onto the heap if it wishes" - then yes I think we're talking about the same thing. That would be the way to go. Thank you.