# When to use unique_ptr instead of local object?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm wondering when we should use `unique_ptr` (or `boost::scope_ptr`) instead of local object.

There are two possible cases I can think of:

1. The object is large that exceed stack size of a thread. But in this case you can always increase size of thread.
2. Polymorphism. e.g. `unique_ptr<C> p; if ... p.reset(new C1); else p.reset(new C2);`. But I am not sure when exactly we need this. If this `p` is a parameter for a function, we can simply say: `if ... foo(new C1); else foo(new C2);`

Are there any other cases that we should use `unique_ptr` instead of local object?

Comment: `unique_ptr` doesn't create a brand new storage duration type. So, your question really is about using the stack vs using the heap. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599308/proper-stack-and-heap-usage-in-c?rq=1) should help.

Comment: Your first reason is a rather esoteric one IMO. An object representing such a huge amount of data will very likely have it allocated internally on the heap anyway (for example, a `std::vector` or a `std::string`). Changing the stack size always has the smell of hacking. YMMV.

Comment: @Pradhan I will use heap if I need a variable lives longer than the scope it declared, same as the answer of the link you provided. But in this case I would prefer `shared_ptr`. I still can't see the best situation that suits `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 11):

### Polymorphism

Polymorphism is a common reason. A typical example is your object is created by a factory that returns a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<C> factoryFunction(int arg) {
  switch (arg) {
    case 1:
      return std::make_unique<C1>();
    case 2:
      return std::make_unique<C2>();
    default:
      return nullptr; 
  }
}

void someFunction(int arg) {
  auto c = factoryFunction(arg);
  if (c) {
    // do something with c...
  }
}
```

### Transfer ownership

In your comment you say you prefer `shared_ptr` if you need a variable that lives longer than the scope it is declared. I think you should actually prefer `unique_ptr`. By returning a `unique_ptr` you are transferring ownership to the caller. Like `factoryFunction` does above. Or perhaps to return a big expensive-to-move object:

```
using BigArray = std::array<BigPOD, 1000>;

std::unique_ptr<BigArray> getBig() {
  auto big = std::make_unique<BigArray>();
  // fill big...
  return big;
}
```

`unique_ptr` has less overhead than `shared_ptr` and it makes ownership clearer. I would only use `shared_ptr` if ownership needs to be shared.

Passing a `unique_ptr` into a function means you are transferring ownership into the function (a "sink"). For example a constructor:

```
class Foo {
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<BigArray> array_;
 public:
  Foo(std::unique_ptr<BigArray> array) : array_(std::move(array)) {}
};

void someFunction() {
    auto big = getBig();
    auto foo = Foo(std::move(big));
    // do something with foo...
}
```