# Qt: Calling MainWindow::Ui from another class using signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt

I made a simple Qt project to cover the issue of calling Ui from another class.

**The Files:**
mainwindow.h | mainwindow.cpp | client.h | client.cpp | main.cpp

**The Issue:**
Connecting a signal from *client.cpp* to a slot in *mainwindow.cpp* worked very well.
But when I added a

```
ui->statusBar->showMessage("message");
```

in the slot, it didn't work.
NOTE: When I made the signal and the slot both in *mainwindow.cpp* it worked, but calling a slot from *mainwindow.cpp* from a signal and *connect()* in *client.cpp* doesn't work.

**The Codes:** (trimmed to the essentials)
*mainwindow.h*

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT


signals:

public slots:
    void doSomething();

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}


void MainWindow::doSomething()
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "test", "BINGO!!");
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("testing");
}
```

*client.h*

```
class client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit client(QObject *parent = 0);
    void call();

signals:
    void connected();

public slots:

};
```

*client.cpp*

```
client::client(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    MainWindow main;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(connected()), &main, SLOT(doSomething()));
    call();
}

void client::call()
{
    emit connected();
}
```

**Added:**
*main.cpp*

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your main.cpp, thanks.

Comment: ok, editted the post

Comment: So... where do you create and use a client object? It looks like that code on the client is never run.

Comment: I have another big project that did this, but i made a small project to cover this issue,  the code of the client runs, and the messagebox also, but the ui didn't. so here's the problem.

Comment: Ok. So the doSomething slot on MainWindow is definitely invoked - you see the message box? The problem is that the following line doesn't seem to get executed and you don't see a change in the status bar?

Comment: Well, now even the QMessageBox isn't called, wtf ?! Please compile it in your Qt and tell me what happens

Comment: You create an instance of `MainWindow` in the main function, then you go and create another instance of `MainWindow` in the `Client`'s constructor. Doesn't seem like something you really intend to do, or do you really want to create two instances of the `MainWindow` class?

Answer (score 1):

```
client::client(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    MainWindow main;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(connected()), &main, SLOT(doSomething()));
    call();
}
```

Your MainWindow lives on the stack. I think by the time your doSomething slot is triggered, the MainWindow object is already long gone. Try creating your MainWindow on the heap instead.

Comment: Sorry to ask you this sillly question: How ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599308/proper-stack-and-heap-usage-in-c . You need to use `new` and store a pointer to the MainWindow. Pass the client as the MainWindow's parent and Qt will take care of cleaning up after the MainWindow when the client object is destroyed.

Comment: I did what you said, "MainWindow *main = new MainWindow;" but still the same issue .

Answer (score -2):

I see a major mistake in the code you have posted.

You have created an instance of `MainWindow` in the file main.cpp and thats the window you see when you run the application. But in your client.cpp you are creating a second instance of `MainWindow` and connecting the signal from the `client` object to the slot of the second `MainWindow` object you create. You are not seeing two main windows because you do not run the `exec` or `show` methods of this second instance.

Now coming to the solution, you will have to connect the signal from `client` to the proper `MainWindow` instance. I will suggest two methods below.

**First**:

I believe you create an instance of `client` in one of the member functions of the class `MainWindow`. If so then shift the connect method to the file mainwindow.cpp

Something like:

```
void MainWindow::someFunction()
{
    client* c = new client();
    connect(c, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(doSomething()));
    c->call();
}
```

**Second**:

If you cannot do what is explained above, then you can use a combination of a static pointer and a static function to get the instance of `MainWindow`. Note that this method can also be used to ensure that there is only one instance of `MainWindow` at any given time.

mainwindow.h

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT


signals:

public slots:
    void doSomething();

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    static MainWindow* GetInstance(QWidget* parent = 0);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    static MainWindow* mainInstance;

};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow* MainWindow::mainInstance = 0;

MainWindow* MainWindow::GetInstance(QWidget *parent)
{
    if(mainInstance == NULL)
    {
        mainInstance = new MainWindow(parent);
    }
    return mainInstance;
}

void MainWindow::doSomething()
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "test", "BINGO!!");
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("testing");
}
```

Now in whatever class you need to get the instance of MainWindow in use, simply use the static function `MainWindow::GetInstance` to get the pointer to the `MainWindow` instance and use that as the parameter for connect.
i.e.,

```
MainWindow* instance = MainWindow::GetInstance();
client* c = new client();
connect(c, SIGNAL(connected()), instance , SLOT(doSomething()));
```