# Create function that returns a QList<int>

Tags: c++, qt

Coming from a C# background, I have some habbits that need to be changed.  I'm tring to return a QList<int> from a function.  The compiler error message is conversion from 'QList*' to non-scalar type 'QList' requested.  Here is the function:

```
QList<int> toCategories(QVariant qv)
{
    QList<int>categories = new QList<int>();
    if(qv.isValid() && qv.type() == QVariant::List)
    {
        foreach(QVariant category,qv.toList()){
            categories.append(category.toInt() );
        }
    }
    return categories;
}
```

I'd appreciate a link to the documentation or a function using the correct syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is referring to the fact that you are attempting to covert between a non-pointer `QList` to a pointer to a `QList`.  You need to either use a pointer to a `QList` as follows:

```
QList<int>* toCategories(QVariant qv)
{
    QList<int>* categories = new QList<int>();
    if(qv.isValid() && qv.type() == QVariant::List)
    {
        foreach(QVariant category,qv.toList()){
            categories->append(category.toInt() );
        }
        return categories;
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can use a non-pointer `QList`:

```
QList<int> toCategories(QVariant qv)
{
    QList<int> categories;
    if(qv.isValid() && qv.type() == QVariant::List)
    {
        foreach(QVariant category,qv.toList()){
            categories.append(category.toInt() );
        }
        return categories;
    }
}
```

Since you are new to C++, I would recommend reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715198/c-pointer-objects-vs-non-pointer-objects).

If I may also point out, your function as listed has a problem where a certain path doesn't return a value (though I suspect that might be because you only copy-pasted a portion of your code).

Comment: Thanks.  So in general if I use the 'new' keyword the storage will be created on the heap and I need to use a pointer to reference that storage location?  (Yes.. I cut and pasted code and put the return in the wrong place.  It should have been a couple line lower... I'll edit the question)

Comment: @DarwinIcesurfer Yes, that's generally correct, though it's more complicated than that.  Look into tutorials/examples of the dereferencing operator, address-of operator, and the use of values, references and pointers.  It may also be worth looking into pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Qt has agressive rvalue support since 4.8, so second variant is much more safer and even faster than first. Because categories var will be moved (not copyed) to outside.