# C++ Classes - dot notation vs pointer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and ->  in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c)

What's the difference between using dot notation and the pointer way?

Instantiating an object with or without a pointer.

Instantiate w/o a pointer = then use dot notation

Instantiate w/ a pointer = then use ->

What are the differences between both? When and why should one be used over the other?

Comment: Are you asking when you should use dynamic versus automatic allocation?  Or when you use the dot operator versus the arrow operator?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599308/proper-stack-and-heap-usage-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102009/when-is-it-best-to-use-a-stack-instead-of-a-heap-and-vice-versa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679571/when-to-use-new-and-when-not-to-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question: in C++, `a->b` is just shorthand for `(*a).b` -- they're exactly the same (Edit: unless you've overloaded them to behave differently!), it's just that the first is easier to type. :)

If you're referring to using `string a;` versus `string* a = new string()`, that's a different topic -- look up stack-based and heap-based allocation.

Comment: Not necesarrily.  Both `operator*` and `operator->` are overloadable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- could you give an example of overloading `operator*` in this context? (Is that multiplication or dereferencing?)

Comment: Thank you. Will mark as answer when it allows. I am not trying to do any operator overloading. The answer given is what I needed.

Comment: The dereference and arrow operators can both be overloaded to do somethign entirely different.

Comment: @Lambert:  Think iterator.  C++ iterators have to have `operator*` work like `*` does for a pointer, whatever it takes.

Comment: Actually...in C++ this is only *usually* true, depending on what 'a' is.

Comment: Ohh... okay, now I see what you mean, thanks. :)  I've personally never programmed or used an overloaded version of the dereferencing operator (indices and `->` have always been enough), so that's why I was surprised.