# Which way is better to create an array of fixed length in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I already know the size of the array to be created.Let it be N.

```
int A[N];
int *A = new int[N];
```

Which way is better/fast ? Why ?

Comment: Don't forget `std::array<int, N>`.

Comment: Note that `int A[N];` is only valid c++ if N is a const. VLAs are not standard c++.

Comment: Note that `int *A = new int[N];` leaks memory unless you call `delete [] A;`

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[N];
```

If `N` is not a `constexpr`, this is only legal under certain compilers, usually with language extensions enabled, or a C++14 compiler. ("Variable Length Arrays")

*Note* this is considered "C syntax" and the modern, preferred way to do this is:

```
std::array<int, N> a;
```

This creates an array of `N` integers *on the stack*. If `N * sizeof(int)` is >= the remaining stack size, you may have a problem.

However: because it is a local object, it has automatic lifetime - it will go away when `a` goes out of scope. Allocating memory on the stack is also very cheap.

Second variant:

```
int* a = new int[N];
```

does not require MSVC+language-extensions nor a C++14 compiler, this allocates memory from the heap equivalent to `sizeof(int) * N`.

It does not get automatic lifetime - you will need to `delete[]` the memory when you are done with it. Allocating on the heap can be expensive, especially in multithreaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

There may be cases where the memory needs of a program can only be determined during runtime. Then you should use :

```
int *A = new int[N];  //it's dynamic memory. Mean it can be change at runtime.
```

Otherwise You should use :

```
int A[N];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Which is faster:**

`int A[N];` is faster because it can be stored on the runtime stack, and when entering the function it will just change the stack pointer by a larger number to allocate room.

`int *A = new int[N];` is slower because you have to take the time to find a large-enough consecutive block of memory. Also, it is less likely to be on an easily-accessible part of the computer's storage.

For more information, see this [related stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation).

**Which is better:**

Regarding which one is "better" overall, it  depends on the specific case.
See [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102009/when-is-it-best-to-use-the-stack-instead-of-the-heap-and-vice-versa) for more details.

Comment: Why allocating memory in the heap is slower than allocating memory in the stack ?

Comment: @DeepakY4-YrBTechComputerS Because if there isn't enough consecutive memory to allocate, then your program might have to wait to do garbage collection to make more room.

Comment: C++ doesn't have garbage collection

Comment: You're right, @MattMcNabb. I meant defragmentation, but that was a mistake since C++ doesn't have that either. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

compile-time array:  C++ 11 has a new container named std::array, like boost::array, which is similar to standard container and can replace the traditional C array.
runtime array: vector is a good choice, you can reserve its size when created. other sequence containers can also be an array.

Answer (score 0):

When N is very large you should use dynamic memory allocation otherwise it will give stack over flow exception.