# C++ create class object in stack or heap when push it to container?

Tags: c++

I have read the this SO issue,[When is it best to use the stack instead of the heap and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102009/when-is-it-best-to-use-the-stack-instead-of-the-heap-and-vice-versa), 
It seems the stack has a limited size, so you can not alloc large object in the stack.

I have some code , which push an object to a container, see this link on online ide, http://cpp.sh/9xxea

So, should I prefer one to another ?

```
void AddPerson(const CPerson& p)
{
    std::cout << "push back" << std::endl;
    persons.push_back(p);
    std::cout << "size " << persons.size() << std::endl;
}
void AddPerson()
{
    CPerson cp(10, "kit");
    std::cout << "push back" << std::endl;
    //I know push_back will copy the element and push the copied object(which is created on heap ?), when function returns, cp will be "freed".
    //so this function is better than function AddPerson(const CPerson&) ?
    persons.push_back(cp);
    std::cout << "size " << persons.size() << std::endl;
}
std::vector<CPerson> persons;
```

Comment: Put the code in the question not in a link. TIA.

Comment: If you are pushing to the container, it will end-up on heap anyway.

Comment: @Borgleader edited

Comment: These two functions are essentially the same (assuming the parameter passed to the first version was on the stack before being passed in), although in the second example `persons.emplace_back(10, "kit");` would be much better. No need for a temporary object then.

Comment: @Borgleader So, if the parameter to the first version was allocated on heap, then after call the function, I need  manual delete it ?

Comment: Yes, if you new something, you must delete it.

Comment: If you are not at the point where its easy to explain the difference between the two functions, I suggest you forget about stacks and heaps, it's not that critical

Comment: You should dynamically allocate objects when you need to control their lifetime, create automatic variables otherwise. Think about stack limit when there is issue with your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, should I prefer one to another ?

I suggest not creating the object separately at all. Neither stack, nor heap. Create the object into the vector directly:

```
 persons.emplace_back(10, "kit");
```

That said, `CPerson` is quite small and you can fit hundreds of thousands (or less, depends vastly on the size of your stack) of them on the stack, so I wouldn't worry whether that one does.